# Determine if an ELF file is signed or not

Tags: elf, binary-format

I need some help in determining if an ELF file is signed or with a valid signature or not.

I have used the `readelf` tool with `-S` option in order to view the section headers and more specifically, the `sig` section header. This is the result I got:

```
[30] .sha256_sig         PROGBITS         00000000000000000  00023276
[31] .sig_key            PROGBITS         00000000000000000  00023676
```

Few questions:

1. Since there are two headers (`sha256_sig` and `sig_key`), does this mean the ELF is signed?
2. How can I verify the signature?

Answer (score 2):

The `-S` flag lists all *section headers*, not "sig[nature] section header". The `S` stands for "sections", not "signature".

Moreover, these section names appear to be quite unrelated to linux itself, but are part of the linux [*AppImage* application](https://appimage.org/), a third party application framework that includes it's own signed update mechanism. The only references I could find to these section names are part of it's update mechanism as can be seen in this [Pull Request](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageUpdate/pull/75).